# Can't see custom object in Salesforce sandbox API?

Tags: salesforce

I created a sandbox and installed an app to test for our Enterprise Salesforce solution. However, in the API, doing a `describeGlobal()` call doesn't list the new objects. I'm guessing it's permission-related, but I can't find the setting. Here's what I've checked:

- The user doing the API query has a Profile of "System Administrator" (Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > System Administrator > Assigned Users)
- System Administrator Profile has "Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All" permission to the object trying to be queried (Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > System Administrator > Objects and Tabs)
- The object itself is "Deployed" (Setup > Create > Objects)
- The installed package has unrestricted API access (Setup > Installed Packages)
- In the normal Salesforce CRM web interface, the user has permission to see and edit these objects.
- Using Enterprise WSDL downloaded after the custom objects were created;

Is there some "expose this object in the API" button I'm missing? Or because these custom objects were created in the sandbox is that messing it up? The custom objects created by apps that were already installed in production when the sandbox was created are accessible just fine.

Comment: if its a managed package then make sure you have a licensed assigned to the user. Also double check your api calls are actually going to your new sandbox and not prod ;)

Comment: I don't see a "Manage Licenses" button next to the application in the Setup > Installed Packages list; does that mean it's not a managed package?

Comment: I am having this issue as well.   Using Enterprise WSDL created via wsdl2java.   This is the error I get when quering for anything other than object's ID: "org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.SObject - Name".     Other custom objects that were created earlier are fully queryable.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak from a .NET perspective.  Any changes to SF requires re-downloading the Enterprise WSDL again and refreshing the web service.  If older objects are accessible then it sounds like the service needs to be updated with the new wsdl.